# unrecognized selector sent to instance only sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, deque, tablecell

I am getting the error

unrecognized selector sent to instance

Which ok  should have something to do with

```
    let nibName=UINib(nibName: "bankCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)

    self.bankCollection.registerNib(nibName,  forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "selectBank")


    let cell = bankCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("selectBank", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! bankCollectionViewCell



let cell = 
  bankCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("selectBank", 
  forIndexPath: indexPath) as! bankCollectionViewCell
```

Which - if it was - then I could perhaps deal with it.  But- the problem does not exist when I run the App in the simulator and choose iphone5.  It only happens when I choose iphone 6 or ipad. So the  cell is named ok.

This leads me to think that the code itself is fine - which then leads me to think - what else could be wrong.  I cannot  fix code that is not wrong - and yet it doesnt work.

The  line of code that is  highlit after the error is the above one -

the message  given is:

```
[__NSCFString zIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd760cc4740
```

From the trace

```
could not dequeue a view of kind: %@ with identifier %@ - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"
```

Which  AHA  you say the  nib has to be registered  - and yet it is (if I use the iphone 5  simulator) And no I dont have any special code to select different  devices.

And again - this code works  in the iphone5 simulator but not 6.

further to the above I have found that if I edit the story board and make the cell size larger - then I have some success.  However I am now facing the issue that as soon as I scroll - the App crashes -  same  sort of error.

Reading around - I am not sure what is wrong - some sort of memory allocation it seems - but I am not  sure what or how

Comment: What is the exception message?  What selector was sent? To what class of object was it sent?  Which line of code caused it?

Comment: Have you tried enabling zombies?  What version of Xcode/swift are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.4.  I have enabled zombies but do not see anything appreciably different - same error

Comment: Please see this answer, this is how I have solved same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329180/7987502

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there:

`let nibName=UINib(nibName: "bankCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)`

I think your XIB name is `BankCollectionViewCell`, with capital letter.
And according to documentation, simulator isn't case sensitive, but real device is.
So solution for you is put correct `nibName`:

`let nibName=UINib(nibName: "BankCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)`

Comment: I would like for that to be right - but sadly the Nib name is bankCollectionViewCell.  Furthermore - in case I was not clear - this  runs in the simulator when I chose iphone 5 - it works fine.  When I choose Iphone 6 in the simulator - I get the error.  So (to my untrained eye) its not a simple "got the name wrong" issue.  I wish it were

Comment: Hum... I had problems like this previous, and sometimes reset simulator, and clear project derived data helps me (goto Xcode preferences, Locations tab, goto Derived data folder, and remove folder, which begins with your project name). Also after that you can do project clean: menu Product->Clean

Comment: Again - I would  like that to have worked - and it sounded so good!!  But the problem persists.  It has me stumped - as if it just always did not work that would be easier.  Note it also works in iphone4 on the simulator

Comment: Try to change cell nib name and cell class name. Maybe it helps